# $lookup the updated name and $group the object inside an array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assuming you have an object matrix on your collection, inside your matrix you have an array of functions
is there a best way to look up the names of functions and actions to check if it is updated also how could you unwind it correctly to have the same structure as this.

```
   "matrix": {
        "functions": [
          {
            "function_id": "635889da9d62263943608658",
            "function_name": "function_name",
            "actions":[
               {
                 "action_id": "635889da9d62263943000001",
                 "action_name": "action_name1",

               },
               {
                 "action_id": "635889da9d62263943000002",
                 "action_name": "action_name2",

               },

             ]
          },
          {
            "function_id": "635889da9d62263943608659",
            "function_name": "function_name2",
            "actions":[
               {
                 "action_id": "635889da9d62263943000001",
                 "action_name": "action_name1",

               }
             ]
          },

         ]
            
    },
```

I tried this kind of aggregation

```
{
    { $unwind: "$matrix.functions" },
    $lookup: {
        from: "functions",
        let:{
           function_id: {$toObjectId: "$matrix.functions.function_id"},
           functions: "$matrix.functions"
         },
         pipeline: [
         { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$function_id" ] } } },
          { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$functions", "$$ROOT"] } } }
         ],                 
         as: "functions"
    },
    { $unwind: "$functions" },
    {
    $addFields: {
        "matrix.functions.function_name": "$functions.name"
        }
    },  

}
```

However I could not get it to correct structure like this

```
"matrix": {
        "functions": [
          {
            "function_id": "635889da9d62263943608658",
            "function_name": "new value function_name",
            "actions":[
               {
                 "action_id": "635889da9d62263943000001",
                 "action_name": "action_name1 Updated",

               },
               {
                 "action_id": "635889da9d62263943000002",
                 "action_name": "action_name2",

               },

             ]
          },
          {
            "function_id": "635889da9d62263943608659",
            "function_name": "function_name2",
            "actions":[
               {
                 "action_id": "635889da9d62263943000001",
                 "action_name": "action_name1 Updated",

               }
             ]
          },

         ]
            
    },
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the difference between your current input and desired output?

Comment: The difference is that my current input is what I initially inserted, the desired output's names are updated, it is supposed to be looked up by the query to check if the names are up to date. the values of function and action are from another collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by duplicating the matrix field to matrix_original to use its structure before unwinding its data

```
{
     $addFields: {
        "matrix_original": "$matrix"
     }
},
```

then grouping them by _id and push all looked up values.

```
{
  $group: {
     _id: "$_id",                              
     matrix_original:{$first:"$matrix"},                          
     functions:{$push:"$functions"},                          
     actions:{$push:"$actions"},                                                                               
  },
},
```

Map the original matrix on node and match the ids from the looked up data if it has the same id it will overwrite the name in the original matrix.

```
result[0].matrix_original.functions.map((func_el,function_index)=>{

                //UPDATE Function names
                result[0].functions.forEach((lookedUp_function)=>{

                  if(func_el.function_id == lookedUp_function.function_id){
                    result[0].matrix_original.functions[function_index].function_name = lookedUp_function.name                    
                  }
                  ....(also map other arrayed field)
                })

})
```

It's not clean but it's the best solution I could think of to a 3 layer nested arrayed object that is related to other collection.

I'm new in MongoDB so for experts out there I'm sorry and rinse your eyes thoroughly for this monstrosity.